# addEventListenner : missing ) after formal parameters

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener

```
function remel(fdx) {
  for (var v = fdx; v < myArray.length; v++) {
    document.getElementById('rswinfav' + v).addEventListener('click', 
      (function (v) {
        return function () {
          setFav(v);
        };
      }(v))
    );
  }
}
```

As soon as I run this in my userscript, I get the error: *missing ) after formal parameters* however there are no ) missing...

Comment: But it works when I run it outside of a function.

Comment: oh, thanks. sorry for the inconvenient

Comment: The issue isn't in the code in your question. Your code is valid.

Comment: But after I removed the semi-colon on the 8th line as one said, Firefox console did not notice me about any error anymore

Comment: I can put your code just fine into my console, no syntax errors are thrown. The semicolon there is not the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
(function(v) {
    return function() {
        setFav(v);
    };
}(v)));
```

with this

```
addEventListener("click", (function(v) {
    return function() {
        setFav(v);
    };
})(v));
```